# Removing hyperlink underlines in Outlook 2010 signature only (not in the rest of the email)

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010, html, hyperlink, email-signature

I am having a strange problem with Outlook 2010, which unfortunately is necessary here.

**In a nutshell, Outlook is adding the blue hyperlink underlining on to my HTML signature, even though specifically the code removes the hyperlink underlining and blue color.**

The HTML signature when copied and used with Gmail, does not perform the underlining automatically as per design, so I know this a problem with Outlook and the way it injects its own code into HTML/the way it parses it.

When creating the signature for Outlook I created a blank signature through Options -> Mail -> Signatures. I then gave it a name and saved it. I navigated to the signature folder @ \Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures and then edited the newly created one. Once I deleted all the HTML code I coped and pasted my own signature HTML in entirety and saved.

This worked, and when I create a new email the correct looking signature appears appended without the blue hyperlinks, however when I send it they do appear at the recipients end. Much to my frustration.

Is there anyway to get rid of this behavior?

I wish Outlook would not change the HTML code.

Comment: Maybe it's the recipients' e-mail clients that are adding the hyperlink, though I am not sure what is being hyperlinked: if you have an e-mail or web-site address in your signature, why would you want to prevent recipients clicking on it? Anyway, there is a solution of sorts, which is to use graphics for your signature, though some client configurations may not display it correctly.

Comment: Yes... Many email clients will recognize the url and automatically "linkify" it in an attempt to be helpful to the reader.

Comment: It goes against the aesthetic design of the signature to have the blue hyperlinks, it's obvious that all the content that I don't want with the hyperlinks ARE hyperlinks anyway. Also like I mentioned above, the original HTML when sent as a signature via GMAIL doesn't add the hyperlink blue stuff. So I think Outlook is trying to *help* me with it's interpretation of the original HTML :(

Answer (score 0):

I've never been able to stop Outlook from adding underlines.
The only work-around I've found is to use an image instead of text in the link.